# Code Analyst ошибка

Tags: code-analyst, c++, ubuntu

Здравствуйте.
OS - Linux Ubuntu 11.10. Процессор AMD.
Вобщем, Ubuntu поставил недавно, поэтому плохо в ней разбираюсь. Установил для нее *Code Analyst*. Запускаю его, создаю там проект, в него добавляю `cpp` файл, жму пуск и мне выдается ошибка:

```
Error starting profile:

This user does not have sufficient permission to run a profile

please make sure:

-You  are root or a member of "amdca" group

-amdca group has the permission to run

 sudo /opt/CodeAnalyst/sbin/ca_oprofile_controller// вбивал в терминал не помогло

 please use "ca_user_manager" to manage CodeAnalyst user// ca_user_manager не

 запускается
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо запускать от рута.

```
sudo имя_программы
```

или

```
su

имя_программы
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте себя к группе amdca (файл /etc/group) и не мучайтесь.

Comment: CodeAnalyst/etc/group - Не помогло.

Comment: Вы поправили /etc/group, вышли из сеанса с окошками, зашли снова, дали команду id и в списке групп Вас нет?

Comment: Ладно, это не получается, тогда напишите как в Убунту 11.10 зайти под рутом это 100% поможет.

Comment: sudo bash 

или новое окно с рутом: gksudo xterm &

Я написал xterm просто потому что не знаю, какой эмулятор терминала родной в 11.10

А что, добавить себе группу не получилось ?

Comment: gnome-terminal